# Adding custom http header to request in MVC 4 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http, visual-studio-2013

I'm looking at possibiliy of needing to add a custom HTTP header to a GET/POST request in an existing MVC 4 web application.

I know it is easy to add custom headers to responses but for requests it seems that it looks a bit more challenging.

I came across this article in researching but it is 5 yrs old now.
[HttpModule to add headers to request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091157/httpmodule-to-add-headers-to-request)

Am just wondering if anyone knows if there is an improved way of doing this in the current day?  (as above example uses reflection this will obviously have an impact on performance with the application)

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to add a header to request?

Comment: its just a last resort option i'm looking @ - I'm beginning to moving away from the idea however as it doesn't feel a good solution to me, but am just curious regardless.